# "must implement the inherited abstract method"

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I had in my class AbstractJpaDao method

```
@Override
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
```

now it isn't in use and I wanted to delete it, but i get error:

The type `JpaAclIdentityDao` must implement the inherited abstract method `IJpaDao.getEntityManager()` in class `JpaAclIdentityDao`.

is that getter necessary? if not how to remove it

my code:

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDao implements IJpaDao {

protected final IApplicationConfig config;

protected final EntityManager em;

private final SingletonEventBus eventBus;

public AbstractJpaDao(EntityManager entityManager, IApplicationConfig config, SingletonEventBus eventBus) {
    checkArgument(entityManager != null);
    checkArgument(config != null);
    checkArgument(eventBus != null);
    this.em = entityManager;
    this.config = config;
    this.eventBus = eventBus;
}

protected void saveEntity(IEntity entity) {
    boolean isNew = entity.getId() == 0;
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        em.persist(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        if (isNew) {
            eventBus.post(new EntityCreatedEvent(entity));
        }
    } finally {
        if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }
}



@Repository
public class JpaAclIdentityDao extends AbstractJpaDao implements IAclIdentityDao {



   public static final String GROUP_NAME_PATTERN = "GROUP_%d"; 

    private static final String GROUP_TEMP_NAME = "TEMP_GROUP_NAME"; 

@Inject
public JpaAclIdentityDao(EntityManager entityManager, IApplicationConfig config, SingletonEventBus eventBus) {
    super(entityManager, config, eventBus);
}

@Override
public AclIdentity findById(Object id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    return em.find(AclIdentity.class, id);
}

@Override
public List<AclIdentity> findAll() {
    return findAllByType(AclIdentity.class);
}

@Override
public void delete(AclIdentity entity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void save(AclIdentity entity) {
    saveEntity(entity);
}

@Override
public AclIdentity createNew(String sid, boolean principal) {
    AclIdentity identity = new AclIdentity(sid, principal);
    save(identity);
    return identity;
}

@Override
public AclIdentity createNew(User entity) {
    return createNew(entity.getEmail(), true);
}

@Override
public AclIdentity createNew(Group entity) {
    AclIdentity identity = createNew(GROUP_TEMP_NAME, false);
    identity.setSid(String.format(GROUP_NAME_PATTERN, identity.getId()));
    save(identity);
    return identity;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getEntityManager` is defined in `IJpaDao` (or one super interface) that's why you need to provide an implementation of it in your class.

If it is not use at all (i.e. even by some reflection mechanism inside some frameworks you are using), then you can remove it from `IJpaDao` and you won't be forced to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to implement all methodes which are defined in the implemented interface. The only possible solutions i can think of, is to implement the method and leave it empty, or don't implement the interface.
Or, as ben75 said, just remove the method in the declaration of your interface "IJpaDao" if you don't need it (anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use it, then throw an UnsupportedOperationException:

```
public class JpaAclIdentityDao extends AbstractJpaDao ... { // Or AbstractJpaDao...

    // Some Code...

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        // return null; (This is not needed, due to the exception thrown above. Thanks dedek!)
    }

    // More Code...
}
```

Due to OO programing, if a concrete class inherits a class/interface with an abstract method, you *must* define that method, or make your class abstract and pass it down the line, like you did with AbstractJpaDao.

Comment: `return null;` is useless in this case

Comment: Yeah... I get code-OCD in some just-in-cases, so that's why I added that.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the Interface IJpaDao contains a getEntityManager abstract method.